# Design solution for many Pojo classes when using Jackson/gson

Tags: jackson, gson, pojo

I'm creating an android application with a server back end. For sending json data between the two tiers I am using Gson(Android) and Jackson(Spring server).

I find myself creating a lot of simple Pojo classes for the serialization from and to json data.

If I have 30 api calls, with different information in it, I will have to create 30 simple Pojo Classes. Actually 60 because they have to exist both on the server and client.

Is there anyway around this 'problem'?

Comment: Jackson allowes to selialize and deserialize Maps. perhaps you can use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below link 
Use @JsonAnyGetter And @JsonAnySetter annotation.

[Mapping JSON with varying object name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388198/mapping-json-with-varying-object-name/34390512#34390512)

Comment: Seems to be the best solution for now. Thanks.