# Jackson JsonMappingException Error - Multiple fields representing property 'PROPERTY_NAME'

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, android-json

I have a class where I have multiple field named `results`, (Actually I have 12 of them, but for the sake of the question, I just include 2 in this question)

```
public class APIRequest {
    @JsonProperty("code")
    public String code;

    @JsonProperty("error")
    public APIError error;

    @JsonProperty("results")
    public APILogin login;

    @JsonProperty("results")
    public APIUser user;
}
```

The reason I have this because my backend API call will always return the `results` field for every request

for example http://api.testapp.com/get_user_profile would return this JSON

The `results` key would then be mapped by `APIUser` class

```
{
    "code": "200",
    "results": {
        "name": "Jackson Liu"
        "age": "21"
        "first_name": "Jackson"
        "last_name": "Liu"
    }
}
```

And then http://api.testapp.com/login would return this JSON

The `results` key would then be mapped by `APILogin` class

```
{
    "code": "200",
    "results": {
        "token": "12u3912edsdnisnknaklsmdlsadmsalma"
        "session_id": "ladlwjopwjwpdmdlndlkadlaasassa"
        "state": "1"
    }
}
```

And because of that, I will get this error.

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Multiple fields
>   representing property "results":
>   id.testapp.android.testapp.jsonobjects.APIResults#login vs
>   id.testapp.android.testapp.jsonobjects.APIResults#user

Any thoughts on how should I fix this?

Comment: This design doesn't scale at all. What if you eventually want to add more types of API calls? You might consider taking a more Object-Oriented approach and simply creating a different object for each type of response that you want. If you really need common metadata for each response, simply use a parent "APIRequest" class that has said metadata.

Comment: I am sorry for the bad question and thanks for commenting. This is my first time using json mapper such as Jackson. I have no idea how to design it. since all requests would have the results key. how would you do it? Could you elaborate more please? Thank you very much @rmlan

Comment: Why do all responses have to have the results key?

Comment: I am the front end developer, and I cannot modify the backend part @rmlan. That is how backend guy made it

Comment: Ok. I completely misunderstood the question. I'm sorry. I thought you were trying to find a good way to serialize this data. You are attempting to deserialize. And yes, I agree with @SatelliteSD. This is going to take a bit more thought.

Comment: @rmlan yea, that way I wouldn't have any parsing to do. Lol. But seriously, I have been banging head on this problem for a few hours.

Comment: @SatelliteSD pass, next suggestion please lol

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485923/java-jackson-polymorphic-json-deserialization-of-an-object-with-an-interface-pr

Comment: Thanks for the help @rmlan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it simple use MAP. Jackson will take care of populating MAP. Just provide setter and getter for each field. And Depends on your context you can read required field in Map

```
public class APIRequest {
    @JsonProperty("code")
    public String code;

    @JsonProperty("error")
    public APIError error;

    @JsonProperty("results")
    Map<String, String> results;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more please? How do I do it in my case? Thank you for answering

Comment: JSONObject is gets mapped to MAP and JSONArray gets mapped to List while serializing using Jackson. So whenever your are not sure about JSON object u can use MAP

Comment: Thank you, one last question, I have other results key that is a List.  `List<APIUserFriends>`. How do we go about it?

Comment: Hi, use below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388198/mapping-json-with-varying-object-name/34390512#34390512