# What is the correct Map format I can have for the following samples?

Tags: java, json, string, jackson, deserialization

I have an input data in String format.

```
{key: value,
 key1: value1,
 key2: value2,
 key3:{key4:{k1:v1,
             k2,v2}
       key5:{k1:v1,
             k2:v2}
       }
}
```

I want to convert this data from JSON to a Java object using jackson:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<???>(){});
```

I am not able to come up with a final map structure to store this data.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to store that into a `Map`? Create a custom object.

Comment: I want to manipulate that data. It is actually json format. So if I can able to get map, then it would be easy for me to get required attribute

Comment: That is not proper JSON format. key4 and key5 needs to be jsonarray, please update question. if you have valid JSON check below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388198/mapping-json-with-varying-object-name/34390512#34390512

Comment: @Tunaki Can u please give me some examples. sunny , format is correct

Comment: You are using Jackson so, you can use JsonAnyGetter and JsonAnySetter. This annotation is meant to consume any type of JSON (nested, N-level). Create custom Object and MAP field with these annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Any json object (even nested) will deserialise using `HashMap` as the target type.

```
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, HashMap.class)
```

I do this frequently.

If you have a json Array, use `List.class`.